# Performance - DRYing up redundant jQuery code across multiple ID selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I know that jQuery ID selector is much faster, but that doesn't seem to lend itself to DRY code. For example, I'm working with a catalog where adding and removing any item triggers the exact same process, so currently my code looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_item", function() {
  id = $(this).data("id")
  addItem(id)
})
```

But I'm wondering (because I am definitely having issues with a slow site, if it'd be better to do something like:

```
array = [1,2,3,...] // array of all item ids
$.each(array, function(index,id) {
  $(document).on("click", "#add_item_" + id, function() {
    addItem(id)
  })
})
```

Question: is the latter example something that is both a bit DRYer and also performant (because it allows ID selectors)?

Comment: What does *"slow site"* mean exactly? Unless you have many hundreds of such event listeners it's highly unlikely what is shown is causing issues. Do some profiling in browser dev tools

Comment: No, it's horrible code (and less concise than the first). Don't abuse ids when you want a class. And don't install event handlers in a loop. That's exactly one of the things that event delegation was meant to avoid.

Comment: Don't believe performance myths and bend them to match your code. While id selectors might be faster for *selecting* *single* elements, that's absolutely not what your code does.

Comment: @Bergi so you're saying keep the code as i had it originally?

Comment: @james Yes. Or, as charlietfl said, profile it to make out the part that's the actual problem, and then make an educated change to that. Or ask us for help on that, but post the profiling data.

Comment: In general, jQuery is slower than native DOM, but easier to use cross browser. One thing (which you don't seem to do in your code) that is a noticeable performance bottleneck is using jQuery `each` when updating DOM content - changing `.each` to native javascript methods (for loops, or `.forEach` for example) on one of my websites improved "speed" significantly, I'm talking from 1 second "rendering" of updated content to **instant**.